# scheduler caught exception: "\xE9" from ASCII-8BIT to UTF-8

Tags: ruby

I have a script which has an error whenever it encounters "\xE9" during processing.

**Output**

```
puts a
{:label=>"\xE9\xBE\x99\xE9\x97\xA8\xE9\x95\x96\xE5\xB1\x80", :value=>20}
{:label=>"c", :value=>18}
```

**Error**

```
scheduler caught exception: "\xE9" from ASCII-8BIT to UTF-8
```

At line

```
# pass in an array with a hash
send_event('report', { items: count })
```

How would one handle these values?

**Solution**

Check what type of encoding from a site like this [UTF-8 Decoder](http://software.hixie.ch/utilities/cgi/unicode-decoder/utf8-decoder).

Loop through **:label** to apply the correct encoding.

```
a.each do |data|
  data[:label].force_encoding("UTF-8")
end
```

Thanks

Comment: Paste relevant code may help you describe your problem clearly. Which line did the exception arise?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's better know [**How To Ask**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask). Given your description about your problem, those who are interested in the question and willing to help have to ask a lot to make the question specific, on-topic and clear. It turns out that the helpers are asking questions and you are answering them. Strange.

- What problem you are working on?
- On what system environment? (Default locale, default system encoding?)
- Where does the data `:label=>"\xE9\xBE\x99\xE9\x97..."` come from?
- What tools/libraries are you using? i.e. the scheduler
- What is the context of the error-prone line? i.e. the code surrounding it, the call stack
- ...

To try to give some help based on your description, you can go and check what actual encoding of `:label=>"\xE9\xBE\x99\xE9\x97..."` is. Apply correct encoding before processing it:

```
a.each do |data|
  data[:label].force_encoding(CORRECT-ENCODING)
end
```

And, it seems that the bytes in `a[0][:label]` represents a UTF-8 string `"龙门镖局"`, so you need to specify its encoding like:

```
a[0][:label].force_encoding("UTF-8")
```